# How to implement a 3D sparse_tensor_dense_matmul operation in pytorch (or tf)?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, pytorch, sparse-matrix

If I have two tensor, a sparse tensor `A` and a dense tensor `B`, `A.shape` is `[batch_size, m, n]`, `B.shape` is `[batch_size, n, k]`, how can I implement a function `f` that can perform the following task efficiently:`C = f(A, B)`, `C.shape` is `[batch_size, m, k]`, and for any `batch` < `batch_size`, `C[batch]` = `matmul(A[batch], B[batch])`, this function should support `backward` method.

I try to use for loop and `torch.sparse.mm`, however, this method does not get the most of GPU. How can I parallelize these operations? (I don't mean torch.nn.DataParallel or something like that.)
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How sparse and how big is `A` in your case? It might be easier & faster to just use dense operations. Also AFAIK PyTorch supports COO format only which isn't the fastest in case of your operation.

Comment: A is around 20,000 * 20,000, which is too large to use dense operation.